# JavaScript: Generating a Random Number According to User Input

Tags: javascript, random

I wish to build a very simple web page which generates a random number (integer) corresponding to three parameters provided by the user:

1. A bottom limit number (the output can't be smaller than this number).
2. An upper limit number (the output can't be bigger than this number).
3. A value between 1 and 9 that defines the number of digits composing the number (length). For example, if the number was set to be anywhere between 1 and 999, this parameter will define whether the resulting number will be somewhere between 1 and 9, 10 and 99, and 100 and 999.

So far, this is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--
https://docs.google.com/document/d/15tsEtcmWrukVp8NBBxQnBpW-YoegjD_fpyhAgH_7ijA/edit
-->

<form name="settings">

How many numbers should be generated? <input type="number" min="1" max="6" name="digits"/>
<br/>
Smallest number in the range <input type="number" min="1" max="999998" name="lownum"/>
<br/>
Biggest number in the range <input type="number" min="2" max="999999" name="highnum"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="validate()">

</form>

<script>

function validate(){
if(parseInt(document.settings.lownum.value)>parseInt(document.settings.highnum.value))
    {
        alert("!");
    }
    else
        {
            document.write(Generator());
        }
}

function generator() {
    var min = parseInt(document.settings.lownum.value);
    var max = parseInt(document.settings.highnum.value);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min
}

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I think I got the lower/upper limit figured out, but I can't say the same regarding the number of digits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function lineGenerator() {

    // Array is better than this, but I'm keeping my answer the simplest
    var result = ''; 

    // Assume it's already validated
    var amount = document.settings.numbers.value; 

    // Build the string
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        if (result) {
            result += ', ';
        }
        result += generator();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thaks @pavelkoryagin!
I inserted your suggestions into my code (see edited snippet), but it doesn't work as expected - the generated numbers do not comply with the rules set. What I'm doing wrong?

**Moreover**, I didn't understand the suggested `if` statement. If I'm not mistaken, `result` is an empty string, and it will always be false. Therefore, `result += ', ';` will never be exectued. Right?

Comment: @voronoi result is initially empty. But after the first loop of `result += generator();` it becomes non-empty.

Comment: @voronoi I've just pressed "Run code snippet" in the question and got exactly what I expected - the list of random numbers, separated by a comma. Feel free to ask me the meaning of any other lines of this code.

Comment: @voronoi Seems I misunderstand the question. In the code the field is labeled as "numbers", but in question description it is described as digits. Sorry, my answer at the moment is not doing exactly what you expect. georg's answer is relevant then.

Comment: I see (I changed "numbers" to "digits" for clarification). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi @pavelkoryagin, the task I was given was changed to something far simpler. I am required to build a code that generates a series of random single or double-digit numbers. The user determines how many of those numbers will be generated (up to 6), what would be the smallest number and what would be the biggest. For that purpose, your code works very well. Just for the sake of learning, could you elaborate on the code? Specifically, why the `if (result)`?